# Oracle SQL Developer is crashing immediately after start

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded both SQL with JRE and without JRE from Oracle.com.
But as soon as I open any of them, they load normally and open a worksheet. A oracle tracking dialog pops and it immediately crashes without showing any errors.

Could you please help?
[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QJVh.png)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2w8k.png)

Comment: Tip of the day? That feature was removed YEARS ago. What version did you download?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it matters but I believe that SQL Developer needs to be used with Java SDK, JRE is not sufficient for it.

Anyway, best option to debug it and/or catch the crash is to run the SQL Developer from command prompt (CMD.EXE) in Windows, or terminal in Linux. You will see Java console output in the command prompt and that can give you hint in what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the root cause was the out-of-the-box memory configuration which is not appropriate for an 64 bit system. While SQL Developer requires about 750 MB of RAM just to start up on Windows 10 in 64 bit mode and any following action requires more memory, the out-of-the-box configuration only allows up to 800 MB. As a result, SQL Developer is closed quite quickly after start-up without any warning.

In order to fix this issue, change the following settings in the file `[INSTALLDIR]\ide\bin\ide.conf` from

```
AddVMOption  -Xms128M
AddVMOption  -Xmx800M
```

to

```
AddVMOption  -Xms256M
AddVMOption  -Xmx2048M
```

That should be sufficient as SQL Developer usually allocates around 1000-1300 MB during operation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's disable the feature tracking and check for updates.

For a 18.x install:

1. Go to system18.x.x.x.x\o.sqldeveloper\product-preferences.xml file under the folder that owns the SQL Developer user settings.
2. Find the o.sqldeveloper\product-preferences.xml file
3. Insert/edit the following:

[image]

For automatic check for updates - off, add these to the sqldeveloper.conf
AddVMOption -nonag

AddVMOption -Dide.cfu.autoskip=true

Run sqldeveloper -nonag

Comment: I have a correction. It wasn't tip of the day. It was Oracle Usage Tracking. It cannot be an old version as it I have downloaded officially on 02-10-2018.

Comment: my advice doesn't change though - get the stack dump, look for the jvm borking, find the 'bad dll' or driver resource

Comment: I haven't got any of those messages too. I opened it using CMD and it simply opens till Oracle Usage Tracking and shuts itself. The CMD isn't showing any messages

Comment: <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>  
    <ide:preferences xmlns:ide="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ide/hash">  
      <hash n="oracle.ideimpl.usages.UsagesPrefs">  
          <value n="track-usages" v="false"/>  
      </hash>  
    </ide:preferences>

Comment: tried to include that xml in the answer, but couldn't get it to go, apologies